# Convert sympy tree to svg string

Tags: svg, sympy

I'm new to sympy. I need to convert sympy tree expression to svg string. For instance:

```
a = sympify("1/5-x")
b = sympify("x-46/x")
res = a + b
```

and I want to convert `res` to svg string. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

copy the output of `print('$%s$' % latex(res))` and paste as input [here](https://latextosvg.com/) to get the svg file which looks like this

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I need to get svg string programmatically in order to dynamically insert it in my application...